# Problems Installing Rails on Mac M3 Chip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line

I am trying to install rails on my mac. I already have rvm and ruby. I ran this command:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

I got the following output:

```
familyrutscher@Familys-MacBook-Pro ~ % rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Comment: that doesn't work either...

Comment: what was the output of 'sudo gem install rails' ?  Did it install ?  Did it fail?

Comment: Don't use sudo to install gems.

Comment: What OS version? Ruby version? Are you using any kind of ruby manager like RVM or rbenv?